# "Component Not Found for identifier <id>.getParent()" in facelets composite component

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I migrated some of my facelets custom components into proper composite components, but encounters the following error while rendering a view that contains the composite component:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /WEB-INF/taglib/cctest.xhtml @15,26 <composite:interface> Component Not Found for identifier: bodyId.getParent().
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.InterfaceHandler.validateComponent(InterfaceHandler.java:135)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.InterfaceHandler.apply(InterfaceHandler.java:125)
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:320)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:379)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:326)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:142)
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:188)
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:164)
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:906)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.jav
```

In the error message, the name `bodyId` refers to the id of `<h:body>` in the file below, and `getParent()` is hardcoded during the creation of the exception message. `@15,26` refers to the end of `<composite:interface>` in cctest.xhtml below.

Here is the page that contains the composite component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:bam="http://bam.mycompany.com/jsftaglib" 
>

<f:view locale="en" id="viewId">
  <h:head id="headId">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body id="bodyId">
    <bam:cctest value="hello world."/>
  </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Here is the file named `cctest.xhtml` that declares the composite component `cctest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  >

  <h:head>
    <title>not used</title>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>
    <composite:interface>
      <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
      <h:outputText id="text_#{cc.attrs.value}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
    </composite:implementation>
  </h:body>

</html>
```

The composite component is declared in a file named bam.taglib.xml located in /WEB-INF/taglib/, next to `cctext.xhtml`. Here is the file:

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">

  <namespace>http://bam.mycompany.com/jsftaglib</namespace>

  <tag>
    <tag-name>cctest</tag-name>
    <source>cctest.xhtml</source>
  </tag>

</facelet-taglib>
```

I'm using mojarra 2.1.21 into tomcat 7.0.41. My faces-config.xml file is empty, there's no managed beans or other custom-defined components (validator, etc.). Web.xml only declares a few context param, plus the faces servlet mapped on *.xhtml; here are those context parameters:

- javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD = 1
- javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS = false
- javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES = /WEB-INF/taglib/bam.taglib.xml
- javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE = Development
- javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS = false
- javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL = true

Looking at the component tree that is displayed in the facelets error page, there's no element named `bodyId`, which might be a hint for my issue. A copy of which is displayed below:

```
<UIViewRoot id="j_id1" inView="true" locale="en" renderKitId="HTML_BASIC" rendered="true" transient="false" viewId="/pages/composite_component_test.xhtml">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <UIOutput id="headId" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> <title>Title</title>
  </UIOutput>
</UIViewRoot>
```

Many thanks in advance for looking at this issue.

Comment: In `JSF 2.0 composite componenets` doesn't need to be loaded through `.xml` file . Follow this post http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/ to implement your `CCs`

Comment: It works this way, thanks. I don't know where I got this non-working config from.

Comment: The configuration you have is for custom tag library. Composite components are different from custom tag lib

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this type of error occur in Development mode when referencing a component from another component via an include e.g.

```
<composite:implementation>
    <ui:include src="/resources/mycomponents/component1.xhtml" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Instead one should use appropriate JSF Component referencing syntax

e.g.

```
<mycomponents:component1/>
```

Strangely this error doesn't happen if one switches to Production mode and all works fine.